# Pre-processing features before applying cross-validation without leakage

Tags: cross-validation, h2o, feature-extraction

I want to do some pre-processing (scaling, feature engineering, for instance target encoding) with cross-validation. I know that the best and theoretically right way to do this is to pre-process the data separately for each train/test step of the cross-validation.

However, I am using H2O, which, unless I'm mistaken, doesn't allow me to create a pre-processing pipeline.

A [h2o documentation page on target encoding](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/target-encoding.html) offers a workaround to avoid leakage from training folds to the validation fold: "The target average is calculated on the out of fold data to prevent overfitting." So the pre-processing on a given fold excludes data from this fold.

It looks to me that this avoids leakage from the training sample to the test sample, but the opposite seems not true.

Can I safely use this workaround (provided the #observations >> #features)  or should I be looking for another framework allowing pre-processing pipelines (or doing cross validation by hand) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent overfitting you can set the `hold_out` parameter to "KFOLD" for the training set and "None" for the test set.

For more details, I'd recommend focusing on the [Holdout Type](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/target-encoding.html?#holdout-type) section of the docs on Target Encoding.

Comment: Thank you Lauren, that is precisely the method I was referring to. But it differs from the traditional method where the feature is recalculated for each step of the cross-validation (with one hold-out fold), and I was wondering about the possible consequences.

Comment: Hi @PierreC, this method is currently only intended to be used with a train and validation split. If you do the automatic cross-validation triggered by setting the `nfolds` parameter you could definitely have leakage issues. Your best bet is to do careful manual cross validation or try to insure you don't have levels with very low counts.

Comment: Thank you Lauren for these clarifications